# How to force new state in React (Hooks) for textarea when clicking on another element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

- [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-jones-ri58v) sandbox
- [github.com](https://github.com/coderootme/TinyWiki) repository

I am creating this small Wiki project.

My main component is `Editor()`, which has `handleClick()` and `handleModeChange()` functions defined.

`handleClick()` fires when a page in the left sidebar is clicked/changed.

`handleModeChange()` switches between `read` and `write` mode (the two icon buttons in the left sidebar).

When in `read` mode, the clicking on different pages in the left sidebar works properly and changes the main content on the right side.

However, in `write` mode, when the content is echoed inside `<TextareaAutosize>`, the content is not changed when clicking in the left menu.

In `Content.js`, I have:

```
<TextareaAutosize
  name="textarea"
  value={textareaValue}
  minRows={3}
  onChange={handleMarkdownChange}
/>
```

`textareaValue` is defined in `Content.js` as:

```
const [textareaValue, setTextareaValue] = useState(props.currentMarkdown);

const handleMarkdownChange = e => {
  setTextareaValue(e.target.value);
  props.handleMarkdownChange(e.target.value);
};
```

I am unsure **what is the correct way** to handle this change inside textarea. Should I somehow force `Editor`'s child, `Content`, to re-render with `handleClick()`, or am I doing something completely wrong and would this issue be resolved if I just changed the definition of some variable?

I have been at this for a while now...

Comment: When state becomes complicated, it is usually a good idea to use [reducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update `textareaValue` whenever `props.currentMarkdown` changes. This can be done using `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTextareaValue(props.currentMarkdown);
}, [props.currentMarkdown]);
```

[image: Edit reverent-breeze-cwyfw]

---

**Problem:**

```
const [textareaValue, setTextareaValue] = useState(props.currentMarkdown);
```

`useState` will use `props.currentMarkdown` as the initial value but it doesn't update the current state when `props.currentMarkdown` changes.

---

**Unrelated:**

The debounce update of the parent state can be improved by using `useRef`

```
const timeout = useRef();

const handleMarkdownChange = (newValue) => {
    if (timeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }
    timeout.current = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("fire");
        const items = [];
        for (let value of currentData.items) {
            if (value["id"] === currentData.active) {
                value.markdown = newValue;
                value.unsaved = true;
            }
            items.push(value);
        }
        setCurrentData({ ...currentData, items: items });
    }, 200);
};
```

using `var timeout` is bad because it declares `timeout` on every render, whereas `useRef` gives us a mutable reference that is persisted across renders

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot! I have a lot to learn.